# Padding issue with TextFields

Tags: codenameone

I have added 2 containers to East to try and force Preferred Height, with the results the same as without the 2 containers, as shown in the image I attached [image: Stealing Padding]. Anybody have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add more than one component/container to any side in a border layout. You need to nest components in a container.

In border layout NORTH/SOUTH override the EAST/WEST. You can use two separate containers to achieve what you want:

```
Container parent = new Container(new BorderLayout());
parent.add(EAST, cmp1);
parent.add(WEST, cmp2);
Container child =  new Container(new BorderLayout());
parent.add(CENTER, child);
child.add(NORTH, topCmp);
child.add(SOUTH, bottomCmp);
child.add(CENTER, centerContent);
```

Comment: Thanks, Shai. I will keep playing with the layout until I get the gui builder running. Thanks for your help on that, also.